# Add Linter Rule: to localize magic strings - Flutter

Tags: flutter, rules, linter, magic-string

I am basically looking for linter rule to recommend the team to localize the magic string in flutter. I am using Visual Code. Do you guys know anything about this?

Can I do that? I surfed a-lot but didn't find the rule yet. And, I am new to flutter as well.

Or, any linter rule for 'Flutter analyze'!!

Thank You.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am in the exact same situation now.

Comment: Not exactly. I had to do manual way.